# Is f(x)=x-[x] continuous at integer points?

Tags: real-analysis

[x] is continuous for at non-integer points in R,so x-[x] is also continuous at non-integer points. But what happens at integer points? How to prove continuity by epsilon-delta or discontinuity by sequental criteria in this case?

Comment: Is $g(x)=[x]$ continuous at integer points? Also please see https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: Please clarify the meaning of $\left[ x \right]$. It can refer to numerous functions.

Answer (score 0):

Let $n_0$ be an integer. Note that $f(n_0) = n_0 - [n_0] = 0$.
On the other hand, consider the sequence $x_n = n_0 - \frac{1}{2n}$.

Then, we have $f(x_n) = x_n - [x_n] = n_0 - \frac{1}{2n} - (n_0 - 1) = 1 - \frac{1}{2n}$.
Note that we got $[x_n] = n_0 - 1$ from the fact that $n_0$ is an integer and $0 < \frac{1}{2n} < 1$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$.

Thus, we get that $f(x_n) \to 1 \neq f(n_0)$ even though $x_n \to n_0$. Thus, $f$ is not continuous at $n_0$.

As $n_0$ was an arbitrary integer, we get that $f$ is not continuous at *any* integer.